# SAS: DATA STEP vs. PROC SQL

Tags: sas

Does anybody know why proc sql can not be used in DATA STEP in SAS/

For example,

```
DATA test;
set lib.table;
  PROC SQL;
   ...
  QUIT;
  ...some operators...
RUN;
```

After PROC SQL..RUN; on operators are not processed.

Thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because like all PROC's - it operates on/produces a **dataset** - it doesn't make sense inside a **data step**. You can use the FROM clause of SQL to specify an input (similar to the datastep `set <setname>`), and you can create a new dataset as output by using SQL's `CREATE TABLE` (similar to `data <setname>`).

```
proc sql;
    create table lib.new_table as select * from lib.table;
run;
```

There's nothing to stop you mixing the functionality of one with the other using views where appropriate, eg:

```
data lib.new_set_view / view=lib.new_set_view;
    set lib.some_set;
    /* do normal operations and output's */
run;

proc sql;
    create table lib.other_set as select * from lib.new_set_view where something='whatever';
quit;
```

Answer (score 3):

Jon's entirely correct, but I will add that in 9.4, `dosubl` does allow this functionality in a way (though it's generally not a great idea, due to speed issues):

```
%macro procsql(sex);
%global mycount;
proc sql noprint;
select count(1) into :mycount from sashelp.class where sex="&sex.";
quit;
%mend procsql;

data addcount;
set sashelp.class;
rc=dosubl('%procsql('||sex||')');
count = input(symget("mycount"),best12.);
run;
```